# Dart generics: "The name T isn't a class" when trying to create an instance of T

Tags: generics, dart

I have a generic "container", which, among other things, needs to be able to create an instance of its "type parameter":

```
class Item { }

class BaseContainer<T extends Item> {
  T makeNew() {
    return new T() as T; // compile-time error
  }
}
```

This, however, results in a compile-time error near `new T()`: "The name 'T' isn't a class. Try correcting the name to match an existing class".

For comparison, defining the method inside the subclass works correctly because I can avoid using the type parameter in this case:

```
class Container extends BaseContainer<Item> {
  Item makeNew() {
    return new Item(); // works correctly
  }
}
```

but that is suboptimal because I would need to define this method in every subclass of `BaseContainer`.

Is there a way to have a "generic" `makeNew` method in the generic superclass?

Comment: How do you mean to instantiate a type parameter?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin: Well, my understanding is that the type parameter would be "substituted" with a concrete class which does have a constructor. I even say `<T extends Item>` and, as a result, I can invoke `Item`'s methods on instances of `T`, so I expected constructing would work the same.

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited. Imagine you have two interitors from `Item`: classes `ClassA` and `ClassB`. They need instances of types `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` respectively and they receive 'em in their only constructors they declare. So there is no way to safely instantiate a type that could be created from this generic declaration (I have no experience in C++, but AFAIK that's how templates work here). So with this in mind Dart, Java, Kotlin and several other popular languages do notneither create a type or allow to instantiate it using default constructor: it is not a safe operation

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Dart generics are like C++ templates in this regard.